# IE 7 - getting extra padding on bottom of footer, any fixes?

Tags: internet-explorer-7, padding, margin, extra

Here is my css for my footer. It is supposed to be at the very bottom of the page, but for some reason in IE 7 .. i am getting about 10px of extra margin. Any fixes?

```
 /*  FOOTER ********************************************************************************************************************/

 #footer-bg                          { margin: 0px auto; padding: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center; background: url(../images/footer-bg.jpg) top left repeat-x  #123800;  }
 #footer                             {  margin: 0px auto; padding-bottom:30px;  width: 900px; font:11px Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; background: #123800 url(../images/footer.jpg) top center no-repeat; color: #b8ceae; text-align: justify!important;  }
 #footer .footer-nav                 { margin: 0px; padding: 160px 0px 3px 0px; font-size:11px; color: #789a47; }
 #footer p                 { color:#f9ffe9; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; }
 #footer .devby                      { margin:0px; padding: 15px 0px 0px 40px; height:20px; background:url(../images/prosites.png) left center no-repeat; }
 #footer br                 { display: none!important; } /* nuke coded breaks*/
```

Answer (score 0):

Use negative margins.

Comment: yes i understand that, but why would i make them bigger if i am already getting extra, that is why i set them to 0 top and bottom